# Is there a way to seperate a barplot in ggplot that takes the first nth rows, then makes a barplot, then the next nth rows until nrow(df) is complete?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my pesudo code:

```
df <- data.frame("Percent" = sample.int(100,100), "Name" = str_c("John", sample.int(100,100)))

x <- df

p <- ggplot(x, aes(x=x$Name, y=x$Percent)) +
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()

p
```

it creates an output that is a barplot that lists all 100 values on the barplot.

[image]
 I am looking to take the first 20, create a plot, then take the next 20 to create a new plot until the nth row of data. I want to create it so that if the number of rows change between data sets I can still create a report that has ~20 bars on each graph for readability purposes.

I couldn't find in the documentation about ggplot or geom_col() | geom_barplot() about this specific situation. Do I just have to break up my dataset before hand? I would be okay with creating multiple dataframes but I would ultimately rather not do that because it would make a mess of my environment?

Comment: Have you considered using `facet_wrap()` to have all the splitted plots together? You could use @Kent approach and then `+ facet_wrap(~group)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, by adding a grouping column to your data frame:

```
# Create groups within df of max size 20
max_per_plot = 20
n_groups = ceiling(nrow(df)/max_per_plot)
groups = rep(1:n_groups, each=max_per_plot)
df$group = groups[1:nrow(df)]

# Make a plot for each group
for (grp in 1:n_groups) {
  p = ggplot(df %>% filter(group==grp), aes(Name, Percent)) + 
    geom_col() + coord_flip()
  print(p) # Use print to force plot output within the loop
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly exactly what I was going for, I didn't even think to loop it through with a grouping variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

# example dataset
df <- data.frame(Percent = sample.int(100,100), Name = str_c("John", sample.int(100,100)))

df_plots = df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number() %/% 21) %>%                        # create a grouping variable (per 20 rows)
  group_nest(id) %>%                                          # for each grouped sub-dataset
  mutate(plt = map(data, ~ggplot(.x, aes(Name, y=Percent)) +  # create and save the plot
                          geom_col()+
                          coord_flip()))
```

Here is how your new dataset (that has the plots stored) looks like:

```
df_plots

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#        id data              plt   
#     <dbl> <list>            <list>
#   1     0 <tibble [20 × 2]> <gg>  
#   2     1 <tibble [21 × 2]> <gg>  
#   3     2 <tibble [21 × 2]> <gg>  
#   4     3 <tibble [21 × 2]> <gg>  
#   5     4 <tibble [17 × 2]> <gg>
```

You can access each plot from the corresponding column like this `df_plots$plt[[1]]`.

You can access the data that produced each plot like this `df_plots$data[[1]]`.

Comment: I like the tidyverse alternative. I will play around with both of these answers thank you very much!!!